# También hay diferencias en las licencias, limitada a dos por persona en los taxis y sin un límite similar en las VTC

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿A qué se refiere "dos" en "[también hay diferencias en las licencias, limitada a dos por persona en los taxis y sin un límite similar en las VTC](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.xataka.com/basics/que-significa-vtc-cuales-diferencias-taxis/amp)"? ¿A dos licencias por chofer"? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si _dos_ no se refiere a licencias a qué otra cosa puede estar dirigida? Ni dos taxis, ni dos VTC, ni dos choferes!

Comment: @Danielillo la verdad es que yo tampoco entiendo la frase... dos licencias por persona? Qué significa que una persona tenga dos licencias de taxi?

Comment: Ni dicen el país.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cada licencia tiene un único titular y está referida a un vehículo concreto.

<sub>*Fuente [taxi.amb.cat](https://taxi.amb.cat/s/es/professionals-del-sector/llicencies.html)*</sub>

De lo que se deduce que si tengo diez coches, solo puedo conseguir licencia de taxi solo para dos de ellos a mi nombre. Esto impide ser propietario de una flota y especular, aunque las trampas siempre existen.

Comment: Ah ~ por fin entiendo el significado. ¡Muchas gracias, Danielillo!